# how to do ad mediation with adcolony and others in UNITY 3D

Tags: admob, unityscript, unity-game-engine, adcolony

I have been working on some `UNITY` applications with unity 5 and have recently added `AdMob` integration. I have been having trouble  setting up `Admob Mediation with Adcolony` .  If anyone has knowledge of how this process works or how to optimally set up admob mediation with `Adcolony` in unity 5 that would be of great help to me. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You basically have to just setup admob and use the mediation ad unit id instead of the admob ad unit id after setting up the mediation on admob website.

For detailed setup instructions refer the [admob documentation here](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/mediation-networks)